# UIView on UIView and UIButton not work

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

```
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-70);
[self.view addSubview:background];

UIView *background2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.view.bounds.size.height-60, 300, 50)];
background2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
background2.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
background2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[background addSubview:background2];


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 158, 50);
[button setTitle:@"myButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[background2 addSubview:button];
```

button does not respond to touch? Why?

Comment: Why are you calling `initWithFrame` and then changing the frame immediately afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-70);


 UIView *background2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.view.bounds.size.height-60, 300, 50)];
```

`self.view.bounds.size.height-70`  compare this `self.view.bounds.size.height-60` background2 out of frame of background frame

[image]

set your background frame `self.view.bounds.size.height` now it will perfectly works

[image]

Comment: Definitely! Аfter 12 hours of coding, I did not understand what I'm doing! ))

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, I just tried it.
I only changed the frame of `background2` to not be outside of the frame of `background`.